# Chat Backup and Restore

Tags: swift, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am using Ejabberd as a chat server. To communicate with chat server from iOS app, using XMPP. Want to take backup of all the chats on Ejabberd server (Or any other way possible). This backup should be able to restore while given request for the same. How can I do this? Any hint is really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If this protocol describes what you want: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html then you can enable mod_mam in ejabberd and use clients that support it.